# ng-include and src is not working on dynamic change

Tags: angularjs

I've something like below. I am binding countries to a dropdown.

On dropdown change i've to display different views.

```
 $scope.countries = [{id : 1, name : 'USA'}, {id : 2, name : 'India'}, {id: 3, name :'MIGHTY USSR'}];


 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
```

-

```
<div class="animate-switch-container" ng-switch on="selectedCountry.name">
<div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="USA">
      This Text is showing

      <div ng-include="'partials/USA.html'"></div>       -- Not Working
</div>

<div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="India">
     <div ng-include="'partials/'+ selectedCountry.name + '.html'"></div>       -- I tried this as well
</div>

<div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>
     Other Country
</div>
```

I also tried with `<div ng-include="'partials/USA.html'"></div>` & `<div ng-include src="'partials/USA.html'"></div>`.

My app folder looks like below

```
app
    views
        partials
           USA.html
           India.html
    dashboard.html
Index
```

Any solution please?

Comment: post your `countries` array?

Comment: I am using my solution in my project. Can you please reproduce your problem in plunker or fiddle ?

Comment: Please check I added working plunker in my answer.

Comment: please update your question, what you done so far ?

Comment: Finally got the solution. I was referring partials/USA.html... But it  is expecting  app/views/partials/USA.html... Took 3 hrs for this :(

Comment: switch case is not required. direct  ng-include="'views/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'" suits.

Comment: how can get selected country value in corresponding partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give a try like below

change the `ng-options` as below

```
.. ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries"..>
```

then when you select a drop down option, value of `selectedCountry` getting the id value of that option for ex: if you select `USA` then `selectedCountry` value will be `1`, based on that id you can include the `.html` file u want as,

```
<ng-include src="'views/'+selectedCountry+'.html'"></ng-include>
```

and save the `.html` files as `1.html` for `USA` and `2.html`for `India`

here is a [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/re6wFREQkBCkZG5L7C1s?p=preview)

and note that if you prefer naming the `.html` files like `India.html` & `USA.html` then simply change the `ng-options` to

```
.. ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries" ..>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dfZzmpwADk7MQzHlIMLz?p=preview)

Comment: I like this.. why not selectedCountry.Name? USA.html is good.. rather than 1.html. let me try this.

Comment: This example is working fine. But Why not <div ng-include=...> and why <ng-include ... difference please

Comment: its also working please check http://plnkr.co/edit/qtCr0l2QkrvSsOPcYGjX?p=preview

Comment: My original question also works fine. But,  I was referring partials/USA.html... But it is expecting app/views/partials/USA.html... Took 3 hrs for this :(

Comment: how can get selected country value in corresponding partial view?

Answer (score 1):

You should not include html page direct into `ng-include`

Bind you html page in controller

use like this :

**MarkUp**

```
<div ng-include="usaPage"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.usaPage = "partials/USA.html";
```

**For selected Country :**

**MarkUp**

```
<div ng-include="SelectedCountryPage"></div>
```

**JS**

```
// in your selection event like ng-click
$scope.SelectedCountryPage = "partials/" + $scope.selectedCountry.name + ".html";
```

**Updates :**

Here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqPPWZRHdMbLgFqRU2gC?p=preview)

Comment: ".html" is missing i guess "partials/" + $scope.selectedCountry.name+".html" . Let me try this

Comment: ahh ! actually .html missing.

Comment: Something is wrong. your examples are working in plunker and not in my code. :(.

Comment: check html file name with your json name and this are case sensitive.

Comment: If i am printing SelectedCountryPage it is showing as partials/USA.html. But <div ng-include="SelectedCountryPage"></div> is not showing. File name and Json name both are same

Comment: Finally it is working... problem with path. I've to put this <div ng-include="'/app/views/partials/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'"></div> and i was putting <div ng-include="'/partials/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'"></div>........../app/views addition..            3 hrs wasted just for simple one. thanks for your support.

Comment: how can get selected country value in corresponding partial view?

Comment: You can use `service` to set selected Country than you get it from service by load service as dependency in any controller.

Comment: I didn't get. I've asked the same question. Please answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534680/how-to-get-parent-page-dropdown-value-in-partial-page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `{{}}` (as well as a `"`):

```
'partials/'+{{selectedCountry.name}}+"'.html'
```

The ng-include doesn't want that. Instead do:

```
ng-include="'partials/'+ selectedCountry.name + '.html'"
```

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi Huh?

Comment: India is example. For USA also it is not working. Let me try it

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi do you get 'partials/USA.html' as the output in the ng-include?

Comment: Finally it is working... problem with path. I've to put this <div ng-include="'/app/views/partials/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'"></div> and i was putting <div ng-include="'/partials/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'"></div>........../app/view‌​s addition.. 3 hrs wasted just for simple one. thanks for your support.